# function component for state component

Tags: reactjs

I would like to rewrite the function component into a state component. I have a problem with useCallback. Please help.
component function:

```
const App = () => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]); 
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([]); 
  const [currentHistoryIndex, setCurrentHistoryIndex] = useState(0); 

  const handleOnHistoryPush = useCallback(() => {
    setHistory([...history, elements]);
    setElements([]);
  }, [elements, history]);

  const appendElement = useCallback(
    value => setElements([...elements, value]),
    [elements]
  );
```

class component:

```
state = {
  elements: [],
  history: [],
  currentHistoryIndex: 0
}

 handleOnHistoryPush = useCallback(() => {
  this.setState({history: ([...this.state.history, this.state.elements])});
  this.setState({elements:([])});
}, [this.state.elements, this.state.history]);

appendElement = useCallback(
  value => this.setState({elements:([...this.state.elements, value])}),
  [this.state.elements]
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a correct way to use state components callback function

```
  state = {
      elements: [],
      history: [],
      currentHistoryIndex: 0
    }

     handleOnHistoryPush = () => {
      this.setState({history: ([...this.state.history, this.state.elements])});
      this.setState({elements:([])});
    };

    appendElement = value => this.setState({elements:([...this.state.elements, value])});
```